# how to check that my python path is set up properly?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables

I have been trying to fix my path but still get an error in the Anaconda powershell when i type `path`  i get

```
The term 'path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ path
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (path:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can i check that my path is set up successfully?

Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe `os.exists(path)` can help.

Comment: not working i am afraid. I get the same error

Comment: on what OS are you working?

Comment: Windows 10 is my OS